# Load navbar with js then activating dropdown menu within navbar with js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load the NavBar for each html page, instead of copy and pasting it into multiple html pages.  This works fine, however I also have another function to activate the dropdown menu of the NavBar on hover, this function is not working.  How do I get this to work?

HTML:

```
<div id="nav"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Loading NavBar
$("#nav").load("nav.html");


// Activating dropdown menu
$(".top-nav-item").hover(            
    function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true);
        $(this).toggleClass('open');        
    },
    function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true);
        $(this).toggleClass('open');       
    }
);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
dropDownMenu.onmouseover = function() {codeToOpenDropDownMenu};
```

and for closing:

```
dropDownMenu.onmouseout = function() {codeToCloseDropDownMenu};
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  The ".hover" function works perfectly on it's own, ie. hiding "// Loading Navbar".  I did however try your suggestion, but it still did not work.  Is it a ranking issue, where the function stops at "//Loading NavBar" and not continuing to "//Activating the dropdown menu"?